# Special Characters in Hyperlinks - Sphinx

Tags: special-characters, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Suppose, I want to link `"http://www.google.com"` with the text `Search & Learn`. How do I use that in Sphinx ?

E.g. text : Now you can `Search & Learn`_.

`.. _Search & Learn: http://www.google.com` doesn't work as there's `&` in the text.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "doesn't work". Is there any error message? I cannot reproduce this problem. Using `&` works fine for me.

Comment: It Works now. I put the "_" inside " ` " initially. Thanks.

Comment: This question no longer makes sense. There is no error to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the link syntax, not the `&` character.

The underscore must come after the second backtick, like this:

```
`Search & Learn`_
```

Comment: My bad... Sorry for the typo but it wouldn't still work even if the '_' is outside. It's not allowing special chars. like '&' , '.' etc.

Comment: My apologies.. I didn't see it. Corrected now.